# In Android MQTT how to Cancel a Publish request

Tags: android, timeout, mqtt, publish, cancellation

I am using this Mqtt library in Android:

```
api 'com.github.hannesa2:paho.mqtt.android:4.1'
```

I am able to publish requests like this:

```
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.*
...
val message = MqttMessage()
message.payload = msg.toByteArray()
message.qos = qos
message.isRetained = retained

mqttClient?.publish(topic, message)
```

I have 2 questions regarding this:

1. After certain user action, I want to cancel the `publish` request if Mqtt hasn't yet published successfully, or it is retrying due to slow internet. How to cancel a `publish` request?
2. How to set timeout for `publish` request? So that I know that after `THIS` many seconds Mqtt will not try to `publish` again.

Comment: You don't, the best you could do is set the QoS to 0

Comment: @hardillb thanks. But i m already using qos 0, but facing this sync issues.

Comment: With QoS 0 the client will never retry

Comment: well with very slow internet, we have a timeout (20s) and after the timeout we need to Cancel that request. But mqtt with qos 0, responds later than the timeout...

Comment: The MQTT protocol has no concept of cancelling a QoS 0 publish (I'm not even sure you could meaningfully do it at higher QoS)